# nix-info can't find libstdc++.so.6

Tags: libstdc++, nix, tcmalloc

I used nix for some stuff earlier and it worked. But now I keep getting this:

```
$ nix-shell -p nix-info --run "nix-info"
bash: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If I nix-shell in some project it'll first install the stuff, but then when it's done installing it can't run things because of the libstdc++ missing.

Does nix not provide its own libstdc++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was I had `LD_PRELOAD` set to libtcmalloc as in https://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html, unsetting that fixed it.